# Dividing a polygon intio congruent polygons similar to the parent.

Tags: geometry

The below quadrilateral can be divided into four congruent quadrilaterals which are similar to the parent quadrilateral. Each of which can be again divided in a similar way, and so on infinitely.

Parent quadrilateral
[image: Parent quadrilateral]

Child quadrilaterals
[image: Child quadrilaterals]

How are these types of polygons classified? Are there more such polygons?

Some other examples are:

- The A series paper size
- Dividing a square into four and so on.

Comment: [Penrose tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling#Inflation_and_deflation) have this property, though they contain more than 1 kind of polygon.

Comment: This sort of stuff is called [rep-tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile) (not the animal), Simple ones like square, rectangle, parallelogram, rhombus, triangle and the more complicated ones like [sphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_tiling) and [Gosper island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper_curve#Properties).